# Use Pandoc to convert tex file

Tags: html, latex, epub, pandoc

I try to use pandoc to convert my tex file in html or epub. It is not a complex Latex file with Math formule. It is something like a book.

But I have a problem. When I convert the file in pdf with `pdflatex`, the all file is ok. But when I use

`pandoc book.tex -s --webtex -o book.html`

or

`pandoc -S book.tex -o book.epub`

It is as if there was no compilation.. `<<` are not replaced by `«`. Each command, like `\emph{something}`, are just ignored and the word is delete from the paragraph.

In fact, it is as if I had made a simple copy and paste, without commands.

Comment: you may try https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook it converts LaTeX to epub (or kindle and epub3) directly, using `tex4ht`

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of pandoc, I think you needed to tell it the input format, otherwise it would assume it was markdown.

```
pandoc -f latex book.tex -S -o book.epub
```

Comment: Still no compilation :-/ I used `htlatex`, `iconv` and `pandoc` to make the epub. It's work, but it is not really elegant

Comment: well yes, pandoc expects its input to be in utf-8. if it doesn't work with the newest pandoc version, can you post a link to the book.tex file?